# Track membership fee belated

Tags: civimember

I have a question regarding membership fees for the following scenario:

Let's say I have a member who joined in January 2018. He payed for 6 months until June 2018. As we are in October now, he is overdue for 4 months. When i try to extend the membership, i click on "renew" button on his overdue membership. I record a new payment and I assumed to extend the membership from the end of the previous membership. Unfortunatly the membership is extended based on "today" and not fromend of June.

Here the screen from the renew form:

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Best regards,
Said

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tamar is correct that you can change the date - but I assume what you're looking for is to change the *default* date that shows up in the "Date Renewal Entered" field.

I wrote an extension, [Custom Renewal Start Date](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/org.nwu.module.customrenewalstartdate) that does exactly this for a client a long time ago.  I haven't shared it before, but I'm posting it because I saw this request!

Comment: Thanks for sharing that - i can see its applicability - ie if they clicked on 'renew' then clearly they mean to 'renew' - otherwise i assume they would click on New Membership

Comment: Great and thanks for sharing - Exactly what i was looking for! Many thanks for that!

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of the "Date Renewal Entered" field for this purpose - e.g. if you enter a date of July 1, 2018, then a 6 month membership will be extended through December 31, 2018 - the date the payment was recorded can be left as the current date - when you click to view the membership, it will appear as displayed in the screenshot below:

[image]

Hope this helps!